# Why do the next two code sequences behave differently?

Tags: qt, pointers, layout, reference, overlapping

I don't understand why the first code sequence creates a QWidget where the elements overlap, while the second one behaves correctly.
The only difference is that in the first one there is a QVBoxLayout pointer, while in the second one it's an object.
It's about passing by reference vs passing by pointer? I really don't get the subtle difference.

First one:

```
QVBoxLayout vbox;
vbox.setSpacing(2);

QPushButton* quitButton = new QPushButton("Qsdfsuit");
QFont fnt = quitButton->font();
fnt.setPointSize(18);
fnt.setBold(true);
fnt.setFamily("Arial");
quitButton->setFont(fnt);

connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));

QLCDNumber* lcd = new QLCDNumber(2);

QSlider* slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
slider->setRange(0, 99);
slider->setValue(0);

connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), lcd, SLOT(display(int)));

vbox.addWidget(quitButton);
vbox.addWidget(lcd);
vbox.addWidget(slider);

this->setLayout(&vbox);
```

The second one:

```
QVBoxLayout* vbox = new QVBoxLayout();
vbox->setSpacing(2);

QPushButton* quitButton = new QPushButton("Qsdfsuit");
QFont fnt = quitButton->font();
fnt.setPointSize(18);
fnt.setBold(true);
fnt.setFamily("Arial");
quitButton->setFont(fnt);

connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));

QLCDNumber* lcd = new QLCDNumber(2);

QSlider* slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
slider->setRange(0, 99);
slider->setValue(0);

connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), lcd, SLOT(display(int)));

vbox->addWidget(quitButton);
vbox->addWidget(lcd);
vbox->addWidget(slider);

this->setLayout(vbox);
```

Comment: It's been said before, but needs saying again: _Learn C++ before Qt!_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first segment `QVBoxLayout vbox;` is created on the stack.
It is destroyed as soon as the method execution if finished.

In the second segment `QVBoxLayout* box` is created in a heap and it's not destroyed until the widget is alive.

Layouts in `Qt` do their job when a widget is shown or resized that's why they should exist until a widget exists.

More information:
[The stack and the heap](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/)
[Blocks and local variables](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/41-blocks-compound-statements-and-local-variables/)

Comment: "It is destroyed as soon as the method execution if finished." - you mean the constructor? Supposing that the code above is inside the constructor of a QWidget.

Comment: Yes, independently what method it is - a constuctor or any other - all local variables are destroyed when it's finished.

Comment: If you make `QVBoxLayout vbox;` a member of the widget class by placing it to a `private` section of it, in this case it will work. It will be alive until the internal destructor of the widget is called.

Comment: @iuliana You should read about [blocks and local variables](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/41-blocks-compound-statements-and-local-variables/).

Comment: @thuga added your link to the answer